# Nuxt SSR breaks when updating data values

Tags: typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

I currently have an app in nuxt that in some cases when I load the page I get this error in console and the page just simply dies, It stops loading all the other components

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'resolved')
```

This is the call stack of the error

```
_callee$    @   4995173.js:7609
tryCatch    @   1a976f9.js:10241
invoke  @   1a976f9.js:10471
(anonymous) @   1a976f9.js:10296
asyncGeneratorStep  @   bd976e3.js:135
_next   @   bd976e3.js:157
(anonymous) @   bd976e3.js:164
(anonymous) @   bd976e3.js:153
(anonymous) @   4995173.js:7621
globalHandleError   @   1a976f9.js:1724
handleError @   1a976f9.js:1693
(anonymous) @   1a976f9.js:1834
flushCallbacks  @   1a976f9.js:1758
Promise.then (async)        
timerFunc   @   1a976f9.js:1785
nextTick    @   1a976f9.js:1842
Vue.$nextTick   @   1a976f9.js:3198
mounted @   3d9c3ba.js:2783
invokeWithErrorHandling @   1a976f9.js:1708
callHook    @   1a976f9.js:3832
insert  @   1a976f9.js:2843
invokeInsertHook    @   1a976f9.js:5806
patch   @   1a976f9.js:5937
Vue._update @   1a976f9.js:3595
updateComponent @   1a976f9.js:3683
get @   1a976f9.js:4069
Watcher @   1a976f9.js:4058
mountComponent  @   1a976f9.js:3690
push.Vue.$mount @   1a976f9.js:7826
mount   @   4995173.js:8426
_callee6$   @   4995173.js:8474
tryCatch    @   1a976f9.js:10241
invoke  @   1a976f9.js:10471
(anonymous) @   1a976f9.js:10296
asyncGeneratorStep  @   bd976e3.js:135
_next   @   bd976e3.js:157
Promise.then (async)        
asyncGeneratorStep  @   bd976e3.js:145
_next   @   bd976e3.js:157
Promise.then (async)        
asyncGeneratorStep  @   bd976e3.js:145
_next   @   bd976e3.js:157
(anonymous) @   bd976e3.js:164
(anonymous) @   bd976e3.js:153
_mountApp   @   4995173.js:8521
mountApp    @   4995173.js:8399
Promise.then (async)        
(anonymous) @   4995173.js:7631
661 @   4995173.js:8523
__webpack_require__ @   01d6f59.js:85
660 @   4995173.js:7384
__webpack_require__ @   01d6f59.js:85
checkDeferredModules    @   01d6f59.js:46
webpackJsonpCallback    @   01d6f59.js:33
(anonymous) @   4995173.js:1
```

The code that is throwing the error is inside vue in the function `patchVnode`, more specifically this condition right here:

```
if (isTrue(oldVnode.isAsyncPlaceholder)) {
  if (isDef(vnode.asyncFactory.resolved)) {
    hydrate(oldVnode.elm, vnode, insertedVnodeQueue);
  } else {
    vnode.isAsyncPlaceholder = true;
  }
  return
}
```

And this is the call stack of it

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'resolved')
    at patchVnode (1a976f9.js:5746)
    at updateChildren (1a976f9.js:5655)
    at patchVnode (1a976f9.js:5781)
    at updateChildren (1a976f9.js:5655)
    at patchVnode (1a976f9.js:5781)
    at updateChildren (1a976f9.js:5655)
    at patchVnode (1a976f9.js:5781)
    at updateChildren (1a976f9.js:5655)
    at patchVnode (1a976f9.js:5781)
    at VueComponent.patch [as __patch__]
```

For some reason the `vNode` has the property `isAsyncPlaceholder`  in `true` but `asyncFactory` doesn't exists, is in undefined, throwing the error when it tries to access the property `resolved`. For what I could research in the code it seems that this error happes when I update a property value and some computed property uses that value. The parent component code is something like this:

```
data() {
  return {
    loadingResults: false
  };
},
computed() {
  showLoading() {
    return this.loadingResults && this.someOtherCondition && this.someOtherCondition;
  }
}
mounted() {
  this.search();
},
methods: {
  search() {
    this.loadingResults = true;
  }
}
```

If I comment the part `this.loadingResults = true;` or the `loadingResults` inside the computed property the error doesn't appears anymore and the page loads completely (that's why I say that changing this value is causing the error) but that is not a suitable solution. Also another solution is to wrap the component that is throwing the error into `<client-only>` tag but that would increase my LCP, and I wouldn't like to fix it with the tag. Right now I'm really lost on how can I fix this, any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error, i fixed it by changing the dynamic component import  to the static one